# Upload getUserMedia blob with Perl

Tags: perl

I have problem with upload video file - blob, to our server. I tried solve this by javascript, but I have response 403.
So I tried do it with perl, but nothing happend. I know, that when I try create and save empty txt file with perl, it works (it is upload on server). So I hoped, that it will be similar. But it doesn´t work :(
I´m very basic programmer, please apologize me.
Please, how can I save the file to the server?
Thank you very much.

```
<html>
    <div class="left">
        <div id="startButton" class="button">
        Start
        </div>
        <h2>Preview</h2>
        <video id="preview" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div id="stopButton" class="button">
        Stop
        </div>
        <h2>Recording</h2>
        <video id="recording" width="160" height="120" controls></video>
        <a id="downloadButton" class="button">
        Download
        </a>
         <a id="uploadButton" class="button" action="upload_ML_v01.pl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Upload
        </a>
    </div>

    <script>

    let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
    let recording = document.getElementById("recording");
    let startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
    let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
    let downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
    let logElement = document.getElementById("log");

    let uploadButton = document.getElementById("uploadButton");

    let recordingTimeMS = 5000;


    function log(msg) {
        //logElement.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
    }

    function wait(delayInMS) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));
    }

    function startRecording(stream, lengthInMS) {
        let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        let data = [];

        recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
        recorder.start();
        log(recorder.state + " for " + (lengthInMS/1000) + " seconds...");

        let stopped = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        recorder.onstop = resolve;
        recorder.onerror = event => reject(event.name);
        });

        let recorded = wait(lengthInMS).then(
        () => recorder.state == "recording" && recorder.stop()
        );

        return Promise.all([
            stopped,
            recorded
        ])
        .then(() => data);
    }

    function stop(stream) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: false
        }).then(stream => {
                preview.srcObject = stream;
                downloadButton.href = stream;
                preview.captureStream = preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
                return new Promise(resolve => preview.onplaying = resolve);
              }).then(() => startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
              .then (recordedChunks => {
                let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });

             //upload it to server part start............................


               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
               var fd = new FormData();
         
               fd.append("video",recordedBlob);
        
             xhr.open('POST', 'video', recordedBlob) 
               xhr.send(fd);


                recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);  
                downloadButton.href = recording.src;
                downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";

                log("Successfully recorded " + recordedBlob.size + " bytes of " +
                    recordedBlob.type + " media.");
              })
              .catch(log);
        }, false);




        stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        stop(preview.srcObject);
        }, false);

    </script>
</html>
```

and perl file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use File::Basename;

$|=1;         # auto flush

$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS = 0;

my $query = CGI->new;           # ..global query


my $src_filehandle = $query->upload('recording.src');
my $upld_pathfilename = "video.webm";

open (UPLOADFILE, ">",$upld_pathfilename);
my $totalbytes = 0;
while ( <$src_filehandle> ) {
   print UPLOADFILE;
   $totalbytes += length;
};
close UPLOADFILE
```

Comment: *"But it doesn´t work"* What does that mean? Do you get error messages? Do you get a file on the server? Does the file have a size?

Comment: Sorry for my bad describing. I have no file on server. Upload not work at all. In console of Chrome I have only status 403 from javascript.

Comment: Status code 403 means Forbidden. do you have some authentication or security (e.g. CSRF) in place?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code does not look right:

```
xhr.open('POST', 'video', recordedBlob)
```

The `open` method expects a boolean as the third argument, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open). You are sending it a blob instead.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) is an example of how you can send binaray data.